# Abraham Williams Twitter OAuth 303 Error

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth

EDIT:
I'm sorry for making this thread as I've figured out the problem.

Here's what happened:
First, I noticed that the URL being sent lacked a "/" between .com and account/verify_credentials. When I updated that, I got a 404 error. Then I looked at the twitteroauth.php and I noticed that the top one:

```
/* Set up the API root URL. */
public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1/";
//  public $host = "https://dev.twitter.com";
```

was commented out. I uncommented it, and commented out the lower one (which I'm guessing is no defunct or not used?) and now it works perfectly fine!

Thanks everybody, and thanks Mr. Williams for a great Oauth library!

---

I've been implementing Abraham Williams Twitter OAuth library and it's been going well so far until I tried to do something with it after connecting to Twitter. That's when I was getting a 303 HTTP code. I then changed my implementation to the way he implements it on his github site, and I still get the same issue. Does anyone have an idea of what's happening?

apitest.php is where the problem occurs, where the $connection variable has a 303 HTTP code. The corresponding $connection variables in redirect.php and callback.php both return a 200. By the way, all of the files are in the same directory.

Here's the code:

connect.php (The HTML on this page has a button that goes to redirect.php)

```
<?php
/**
* @file
* Check if consumer token is set and if so send user to get a request token.
*/

/**
* Exit with an error message if the CONSUMER_KEY or CONSUMER_SECRET is not defined.
*/
require_once('twitconfig.php');
if (CONSUMER_KEY === '' || CONSUMER_SECRET === '') {
  echo 'A consumer key and secret are required.';
  exit();
}

?>
```

redirect.php

```
<?php

/* Start session and load library. */
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
require_once('twitconfig.php');

/* Build TwitterOAuth object with client credentials. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

/* Get temporary credentials. */
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

/* Save temporary credentials to session. */
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

/* If last connection failed don't display authorization link. */
switch ($connection->http_code) {
  case 200:
    /* Build authorize URL and redirect user to Twitter. */
    $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    break;
  default:
    /* Show notification if something went wrong. */
    echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}

?>
```

callback.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Take the user when they return from Twitter. Get access tokens.
 * Verify credentials and redirect to based on response from Twitter.
 */

/* Start session and load lib */
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
require_once('twitconfig.php');

/* If the oauth_token is old redirect to the connect page. */
if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) {
  $_SESSION['oauth_status'] = 'oldtoken';
  header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}

/* Create TwitteroAuth object with app key/secret and token key/secret from default phase */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

/* Request access tokens from twitter */
$access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

/* Save the access tokens. Normally these would be saved in a database for future use. */
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;

/* Remove no longer needed request tokens */
unset($_SESSION['oauth_token']);
unset($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);


/* If HTTP response is 200 continue otherwise send to connect page to retry */
if (200 == $connection->http_code) {
  /* The user has been verified and the access tokens can be saved for future use */
  $_SESSION['status'] = 'verified';
  header('Location: ./apitest.php');
} else {
  /* Save HTTP status for error dialog on connnect page.*/
  header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}

?>
```

apitest.php (where the problem is seen via a print_r)

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
require_once('twitconfig.php');

if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
    header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}

/* Get user access tokens out of the session. */
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];

/* Create a TwitterOauth object with consumer/user tokens. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);


/* Get logged in user to help with tests. */
$user = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

print_r($connection);

print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

The output of the first print statement is:

```
TwitterOAuth Object ( 
[http_code] => 303 
[url] => https://dev.twitter.comaccount/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=UoXXKdfnVHh2fYD8Csw&oauth_nonce=09bc369393a8eab3a1dc36eaa6230b45&oauth_signature=pe5dYtYq%2FvlGb0c%2BnRR%2BQAXI0Ec%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1314249851&oauth_token=351699791-F6stFFk81poF8ooORgLLxaE2cpSdDT2Vr0Tz9yJm&oauth_version=1.0 
[host] => https://dev.twitter.com 
[timeout] => 30 
[connecttimeout] => 30 
[ssl_verifypeer] => 
[format] => json 
[decode_json] => 1 
[http_info] => Array ( [url] => https://dev.twitter.comaccount/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=UoXXKdfnVHh2fYD8Csw&oauth_nonce=09bc369393a8eab3a1dc36eaa6230b45&oauth_signature=pe5dYtYq%2FvlGb0c%2BnRR%2BQAXI0Ec%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1314249851&oauth_token=351699791-F6stFFk81poF8ooORgLLxaE2cpSdDT2Vr0Tz9yJm&oauth_version=1.0 
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 303 
[header_size] => 565 
[request_size] => 401 
[filetime] => -1 
[ssl_verify_result] => 1 
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 0.053773 
[namelookup_time] => 0.003355 
[connect_time] => 0.006399 
[pretransfer_time] => 0.047636 
[size_upload] => 0 
[size_download] => 0 
[speed_download] => 0 
[speed_upload] => 0 
[download_content_length] => 0 
[upload_content_length] => 0 
[starttransfer_time] => 0.053629 
[redirect_time] => 0 
[certinfo] => Array ( ) ) 
[useragent] => TwitterOAuth v0.2.0-beta2 
[sha1_method] => OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 Object ( ) 
[consumer] => OAuthConsumer Object ( [key] => UoXXKdfnVHh2fYD8Csw [secret] => SyKfxRorvUs6THwj5l26TGEkFOCGf1vG86N7PoS97o [callback_url] => ) [token] => OAuthConsumer Object ( [key] => 351699791-F6stFFk81poF8ooORgLLxaE2cpSdDT2Vr0Tz9yJm [secret] => q8fHaTaFvOUL8XKYX89LSgubr2fSl1xHBUAi8MUqIc [callback_url] => ) 

[http_header] => Array ( [location] => http://guide.a.id.opendns.com/?url=dev%2Etwitter%2Ecomaccount%2Fverify%5Fcredentials%2Ejson%3Foauth%5Fconsumer%5Fkey%3DUoXXKdfnVHh2fYD8Csw%26oauth%5Fnonce%3D09bc369393a8eab3a1dc36eaa6230b45%26oauth%5Fsignature%3Dpe5dYtYq%252FvlGb0c%252BnRR%252BQAXI0Ec%253D%26oauth%5Fsignature%5Fmethod%3DHMAC%2DSHA1%26oauth%5Ftimestamp%3D1314249851%26oauth%5Ftoken%3D351699791%2DF6stFFk81poF8ooORgLLxaE2cpSdDT2Vr0Tz9yJm%26oauth%5Fversion%3D1%2E0 
[content_length] => 0 
[connection] => close 
[date] => Thu, 25 Aug 2011 05:24:50 GMT 
[server] => OpenDNS Guide ) )
```

The output of the second print statement is:

```
Array ( 
[access_token] => Array ( 
[oauth_token] => 351699791-F6stFFk81poF8ooORgLLxaE2cpSdDT2Vr0Tz9yJm 
[oauth_token_secret] => q8fHaTaFvOUL8XKYX89LSgubr2fSl1xHBUAi8MUqIc 
[user_id] => 351699791 
[screen_name] => jibjib21 ) 
[status] => verified )
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on with this 303 error and how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 303 response is a redirect. My guess is you need to add .json (or whatever format you are using) to the end of the URL you are requesting.

I.e. instead of 'account/verify_credentials', you need to request 'account/verify_credentials.json'.

Comment: If you look at the [url] part in the output from the first print statement, .json is already there. Just for good measure, I tried what you did, and it just appended another .json after the first one and still gave the same 303 code. Thanks for the consideration, though.